# regex match only if a substring is the only occurrence and not match if substring plus something else

Tags: java, regex

This a bit complicated. so example might help

I want to match/group values from the following type of string only

`SELECT hello,world from tableName where id = 'hello';`

and NOT

`SELECT hello,world FROM tableName where id='hello' and blah='jjk';`

`SELECT hello from tableName where blah='jjk' and id='hello';`

As you can see, I want to match only `where id = 'hello'` is the only where clause that is present.

I want to group to get columnNames, tableName and id;

Here is the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/anRIrL/2) that I build, but it maches all the above.

NOTE: the value of id is fixed length. That is, it is always 5 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?  Seems to do what you asked for.

```
SELECT\s+(.*)\s+FROM\s+(.*)[\s]+?where\s+id\s*=\s*('[a-z]{5}')\s*;$
```

Regex101 link with some tests: https://regex101.com/r/anRIrL/3/tests

Comment: how about "SELECT", "FROM" and "Where" being case-insensitive?

Comment: Add the case insensitive flag to your regex then.  In Java it's done by inserting `(?i)` at the beginning, or with `Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`.